# Jquery slider controle

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, if-statement

I want to build a content slider which has an arrow on the left and right to navigate. What I want to set the position of the slider +100px (When you click right) and -100px (when you click left). This function works.

But what goes wrong is that I want to disable it to move when it reached a certain x position value. So when a my content has reached the end it has to stop so th euser can only navigate back.

Hope you can help me because I can't find it.

**CSS**

```
#container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#CDFAA8;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left: 13px;
    }

#slider{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#063;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

#block1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#067;
    float: left;
}

#block2{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#079;
    float: left;
}

#move_right{
    height: 150px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #3f3f3f;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    z-index: 200;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

#move_left{
    height: 150px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #3f3f3f;
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 200;
    opacity: 0.2;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="move_left"><button id="right">&laquo;</button></div><div id="move_right"><br><br><button id="left">&raquo;</button></div>
<div id="slider">

    <div id="block1"></div>    
    <div id="block2"></div> 

</div>
</div>
```

**java**

```
$("#right").click(function() {
        $("#slider").animate({
            "left": "+=100px"
             }, "slow");
});

$("#left").click(function() {
        $("#slider").animate({
            "left": "-=100px"
        }, "slow");

});
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to make some check when you click on the slide button.

Here is a code which do it. I putted it in a closure and made it dynamic, just the "step" is hard-coded because your "slider" don't have the width you want it to slide :

```
(function($) {
    var slider = $('#slider'),
        step = 100,
        left = parseInt(slider.css('left'), 10),
        max = $('#container').width() - slider.width(),
        min = 0;

    $("#right").click(function() {
        if (left < max) {
            var newLeft = left+step;
            left = (newLeft<max) ? newLeft : max;
            $("#slider").animate({
                "left": left + 'px'
            }, "slow");
        }
    });

    $("#left").click(function() {
        if (left > 0) {
            var newLeft = left - step;
            left = (newLeft>min) ? newLeft : min;
            slider.animate({
                "left": left + 'px'
            }, "slow");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ok (i'm back from my holiday) and I am checking the script. Which works except for one thing...when #slider is more width than the container it stops working

Answer (score 0):

```
var L = parseInt($("#slider").css('left'));

$("#right").click(function() {
    if (L<400) {
        $("#slider").animate({
            "left": "+=100px"
             }, "slow");
        });
    }

$("#left").click(function() {
    if (L>0) {
        $("#slider").animate({
            "left": "-=100px"
            }, "slow");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The final solution of this slider was:

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#temp{
height: 300px;
}

#container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#CDFAA8;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left: 13px;
    }

#slider{
    width: 1300px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#063;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

#block1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#067;
    float: left;
}

#block2{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#079;
    float: left;
}

#move_right{
    height: 150px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #3f3f3f;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    z-index: 200;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

#move_left{
    height: 150px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #3f3f3f;
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 200;
    opacity: 0.2;
}​
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="temp">
<div id="container">
    <div id="move_left"><button id="right">&laquo;</button></div><div id="move_right"><br><br><button id="left">&raquo;</button></div>
<div id="slider">

    <div id="block1">1</div>    
    <div id="block2">2</div>
    <div id="block1">3</div>    
    <div id="block2">4</div> 
    <div id="block1">5</div>    
    <div id="block2">6</div>
    <div id="block1">7</div>    
    <div id="block2">8</div>
    <div id="block1">9</div>
    <div id="block2">10</div>
    <div id="block1">11</div>    
    <div id="block2">12</div>
    <div id="block1">13</div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JAVA**

```
(function($) {
    var slider = $('#slider'),
        step = 500,
        left = parseInt(slider.css('left'), 10),
        max = $('#container').width() - slider.width(),
        min = 0;

    $("#left").click(function() {
        if (left > max) {
            var newLeft = left - step;
            left = (newLeft>max) ? newLeft : max;
            $("#slider").animate({
                "left": left + 'px'
            }, "slow");
        }
    });

    $("#right").click(function() {
        if (left < 0) {
            var newLeft = left + step;
            left = (newLeft<min) ? newLeft : min;
            slider.animate({
                "left": left + 'px'
            }, "slow");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```